# Simple task regex expression replacing any "%function test%" by test

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the good expression to replace any string starting with :

```
"%function
```

and ending by :

```
%"
```

by the inbetween string for example :

"%function test%" should return

```
test
```

and "%function test%","% function test%" should return :

```
test,test
```

I tried this

```
preg_replace('/"%function (.*)?%"/', '$1',$string);
```

I had great hope at first, coz my first example work great but with multiple function not so great.

For more information you can see the code and try out here (a sort of phpfiddle): http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00232644b801271e2ffb2ddf4cd450ddffcb50c2

Any help would  be greatly appreciated,
best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `?` outside the capturing group, you're making it optional. Instead what you want is a non-greedy `*` so you'll have to do. Other choice is to do `([^%]+)`

```
preg_replace('/"%function (.*?)%"/', '$1',$string);
```

Comment: @Su4p glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use look arounds

```
(?<="%function )[^%]+(?=%")
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lI7cU3/2)

```
preg_match_all( "/(?<=\"%function )[^%]+(?=%\")/", "\"%function test%\"", $matches);
```

Will produce

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                       [0] => test 
                      ) 
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%\s*\S+\s+(\S+?)\s*%
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/8

```
$re = "/%\\s*\\S+\\s+(\\S+?)\\s*%/im";
$str = "%function test%\n%function test%,% function test%";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```